# Running multiple subs one at a time

Tags: vba, excel

I have created a workbook, which I will use to call my other workbooks and their macros from. I have a assigned the sub "knap" to a button, which I will press whenever I need to update. However when I press the button and open one of my workbooks and call the macro, vba does not wait for the calculation in that particular workbook to finish, but it continues and begins opening the next workbook. I have tried to use the command Application.wait, however it seems like it does not work. It will wait but it does not calculate in the background in the mean time.

```
Sub Knap()

Call LongerSeries
Application.Wait (Now + TimeValue("00:03:00"))
Call QuickCorrelation
Application.Wait (Now + TimeValue("00:03:00"))
Call SPX

End Sub

Sub LongerSeries()

Workbooks.Open ("G:\FONDS\Quick financials_Longer Series (2).xlsb")
Application.Run "RefreshData"

End Sub

Sub QuickCorrelation()

Workbooks.Open ("G:\FONDS\Quick correlation_1.xlsb")
Application.Run "RefreshData"

End Sub

Sub SPX()

Workbooks.Open ("G:\FONDS\Quick Intra Corr (SPX)_1.xlsb")
Application.Run "RefreshData"

End Sub
```

Comment: You can enforce calculation by writing `Calculate` in the VBA code. Then it would wait.

Comment: In the sub "knap" inbetween calling the subs?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Did you try using an Array?

```
Sub Knap()

Dim MyWorksheets()

MyWorksheets = Array("LongerSeries", "QuickCorrelation", "SPX")

For Each mw in MyWorksheets
    If mw = "LongerSeries" then
        Call LongerSeries
    ElseIf mw = "QuickCorrelation" Then
        Call QuickCorrelation
    ElseIf mw = "SPX" Then
        Call SPX
    Else
    End If        
Next    
End Sub

Sub LongerSeries()

Workbooks.Open ("G:\FONDS\Quick financials_Longer Series (2).xlsb")
Application.Run "RefreshData"
Application.Calculate
If Not Application.CalculationState = xlDone Then
    DoEvents
End If

End Sub

Sub QuickCorrelation()

Workbooks.Open ("G:\FONDS\Quick correlation_1.xlsb")
Application.Run "RefreshData"
If Not Application.CalculationState = xlDone Then
    DoEvents
End If

End Sub

Sub SPX()

Workbooks.Open ("G:\FONDS\Quick Intra Corr (SPX)_1.xlsb")
Application.Run "RefreshData"
If Not Application.CalculationState = xlDone Then
    DoEvents
End If

End Sub
```

Hope this helps!

Comment: "Can't find project or libary" and then it highlights "mw"

Comment: I updated the script... But what if you would add these three lines to each of those subs?                                                                                          `If Not Application.CalculationState = xlDone Then
    DoEvents
End If`

Comment: It works when i declare the varialbe mw. "Dim mw as variant". Thank you very much!

Answer (score 0):

Try like this:

```
Sub LongerSeries()
    Workbooks.Open ("G:\FONDS\Quick financials_Longer Series (2).xlsb")
    Application.Calculate
    Application.Run "RefreshData"
End Sub
```

It would force the claculation in all opened workbooks. [See more about Calculate here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/vba/excel-vba/articles/worksheet-calculate-method-excel).

Comment: But the phrase "Application.run "Refreshdata" refers to a sub which will import and update bloomberg data with the bloomberg add in, which takes a couple of minutes. There is no calculation involved.